# Ajax is not working when I fetch data from MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I'm building an ecommerce.and for this I'm fetching data products from database, I want to let people add products in cart without refreshing the page, I have tried AJAX but I don't know why but it works only when data is not in a loop, I'm in PHP, and MySQL.
Code:

```
<?php
    $results = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM idd");
    while ($list = $results->fetch_assoc()){
        ?>
    <form method="POST" id="formId<?php echo $list['id'] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="value">
        <!-- <input type="hidden" name="name" id="id" value="value"> -->
        <input type="submit" onclick="upcart(<?php echo $list['id']; ?>)">
    </form>
<?php
    }
    ?>
    
    <script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    function upcart(id){

    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "data.php",
        data: $("#formId"+ id).serialize(),
        // dataType: "text",
        success: function (response) {
            alert("success");
        }
        // return false;
    });
    };

});
    </script>
```

Comment: ok now i have another problem all is going good but, the data is not going in localhost, but its too long and for this i will ask a new question

Comment: Can you clarify more on how this is not working? What exactly is the problem you are facing? Is it that ajax request isn't sent or your `data.php` can't process the request? Is `data.php` this file or another file?

Answer (score 1):

Use events instead of manually calling the javascript function.

We then don't need to generate id's for the forms since it we will have access to the correct form in the callback.

The PHP part:

```
<?php
$results = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM idd");
while ($list = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>
    <form method="POST" class="some-form-class">
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="value" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

The JS part:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Bind the forms submit event
    $('.some-form-class').on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Here we can use $(this) to reference the correct form
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "data.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                alert("success");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ### NOTE: Magnus Eriksson answer is far cleaner

since `function upcart(id)` is not in the global scope, `onclick="upcart(<?php echo $list['id']; ?>)">` will fail due to the missing function

You need to declare that function in the global scope

Also, you need to prevent the form submission properly

```
<?php
    $results = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM idd");
    while ($list = $results->fetch_assoc()){
        ?>
    <form method="POST" id="formId<?php echo $list['id'] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="value">
        <!-- <input type="hidden" name="name" id="id" value="value"> -->
        
        <input type="submit" onclick="return upcart(<?php echo $list['id']; ?>)">
    </form>
<?php
```

note the `return upcart ....` - very important

NOT INSIDE `$(document).ready(function() {` since you don't need to wait for document ready to declare a function!

```
function upcart(id) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "data.php",
        data: $("#formId" + id).serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
    return false; // to prevent normal form submission
}
```

Comment: i love you bro, i was searching for solution for 3 days

Comment: well, that's awkward - I barely know you :p

Comment: I would even recommend to add an event listener on the form submission instead of manually calling a function on the buttons onclick. Then you don't need to mess around with id's either, just set the event on all the forms (you can use a class to select them all).

Comment: yes yes i was doing it, like 10 tries and failure ago

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - the onclick has the id, so you'd need to change the PHP code as well - oh, right, but the id is just to get the form ... nice

Comment: I posted an answer showing what I mean. No id's involved since it will all be event based and you will already have access to the correct form element (since we put the event on the form and not the button)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - yeah, once I re-read the code it clicked in my head! yours is better code